# List Comprehension in Ocaml?

Tags: ocaml

It seems that Ocaml batteries have comprehension syntax:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#OCaml

However, what module should I include to use this syntax? I already `open Batteries`, but it doesn't work. Or is there a more idiomatic way to do list comprehension? I can use List.map and BatList.remove_if to achieve similar results, but that is much less elegant.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Currently there're two libraries in OCaml that provide list comprehension, one was formerly a part of OCaml Batteries, another is shipped with camlp4. Neither is widely used and I, personally, do no recommend you to use any.

For list comprehension to work, you need to change the syntax of the language. This can be done with preprocessing your program, written in an extended syntax, with a `camlp4` preprocessor. Also, list comprehension is not a first class citizen in OCaml community, and it is not well supported by the modern toolkits. Although, you can still easily play with it in a toplevel, for that you need, to install the list comprehension package:

```
opam install pa_comprehension
```

and load it into a toplevel, using the following directives:

```
# #use "topfind";;
# #camlp4o;;
# #require "pa_comprehension";;
# open Batteries;;
# [? 2 * x | x <- 0 -- max_int ; x * x > 3 ?];;
```

But again, my personal opinion that list comprehension is not the best way to structure your code.

### Life without comprehension

The example, you provided, can be expressed using `core_kernel` `Sequence` module (an analog  of the Batteries `Enum`)

```
let f n =
  Sequence.(range 0 n |>
            filter ~f:(fun x -> x * x > 3) |>
            map ~f:(fun x -> x * 2))
```

Hence a `filter |> map` is such a common idiom there exists a `filter_map` function:

```
let f n =
  Sequence.(range 0 n |>
            filter_map ~f:(fun x ->
                if x * x > 3 then Some (x * 2) else None))
```

You may notice, that this examples takes more code, than list comprehension. But as soon as your programs will start to mature from simple hello world applications with integers to something more sophisticated, you will agree that using explicit iterators is more readable and comprehensible.

Also, since libraries in `Core` are so consistent, you can use a simple `List` instead of `Sequence` just by substituting the latter by the former. But of course, `List` is eager, unlike the `Sequence`, so playing with `max_int` using lists is not a good idea.

Moreover, since all containers are monads, you can use monadic operators for mapping, like:

```
let odds n = List.(range 0 n >>| fun x -> x * 2 + 1)
```

Comment: So what would you recommend instead?

Comment: For example, if I want to get something like (in python code) [x*2 for x in xlist if x>3], is there a clean way to do it?

Comment: @user69818: Use `List.filter` for the `>3` conditions and then `List.map`

Comment: @nimrodm yea, it is similar to what I used (I used BatList.remove_if instead of List.filter though, but now I see filter is the right choice, as remove_if only removes the first element matched).

Comment: @nimrodm However, as I mentioned in the question, this approach is much less elegant than list comprehension.

Comment: @user69818: It isn't that bad if you have a pipe operator defined `|>` (see http://www.ocamlpro.com/blog/2012/08/20/ocamlpro-and-4.00.0.html "pipe operator")

Comment: @nimrodm the main nonelegant part is that I have to write, for instance, `fun x -> x>3`, where in list comprehsnive it is simply `x>3`, not to mention that `List.filter` is longer than `if`.

Comment: @ivg thanks for the comprehensive answer. I have no idea what the last expression means. Can you direct me to some references on it (I've only heard of monad for Haskell)?

Comment: The last expression is the same as `[ x * 2 + 1 for x in range(n) ]` in python. Monad can be seen as a generalization of the container, actually monadic map operator is exactly the same as a map operator for any other container. Here is a good [tutorial](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:WW--TtRXT2AJ:blog.enfranchisedmind.com/2007/08/a-monad-tutorial-for-ocaml/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)

Comment: @ivg working link for ocaml monad tutorial: https://web.archive.org/web/20071231141139/http://enfranchisedmind.com/blog/2007/08/06/a-monad-tutorial-for-ocaml/

Comment: This is a rather ancient answer :) Since that time I have implemented the [monads][1] library that comes with its own tutorial, I hope you might also find it useful (both the tutorial and the library, which you can get with `opam install monads`).

[1]: https://binaryanalysisplatform.github.io/bap/api/master/monads/Monads/Std/index.html

Answer (score 2):

list comprehension is already included in standard ocaml

```
#require "camlp4.listcomprehension";;

[ x * x | x <- [ 1;2;3;4;5] ];;

- : int list = [1; 4; 9; 16; 25]
```

Comment: This is no longer the case.