# Building OCaml code that uses list comprehension

Tags: ocaml, list-comprehension, ocaml-batteries

From this SO question: [List Comprehension in Ocaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652428/list-comprehension-in-ocaml), I could install the comprehension package with `opam install pa_comprehension`, and use the package in toplevel REPL.

```
# #require "pa_comprehension";;
# open Batteries;;
# [? 2 * x | x <- 0 -- max_int ; x * x > 3 ?];;
- : int Batteries.Enum.t = <abstr>
```

Then, how can I compile the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, since `pa_comprehension` package name is not ended with `.syntax` extension, this is a little bit harder than it should be. (The fact that this issue is still not fixed, shows that using `pa_comprehension` is not very popular in modern OCaml). So, without the proper extension, we need to do everything manually. If your file is named `pr.ml`, then the correct invocation is:

```
$ ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind -syntax camlp4o -pkg camlp4,pa_comprehension pr.native
```

If you don't wan't to type it every time, then you can create `_tags` file, with the following contents:

```
$ cat _tags
<**/*> : package(camlp4),syntax(camlp4o),package(pa_comprehension)
```

In that case, the command line spell is a little bit easier:

```
$ ocamlbuild -use-ocamlfind pr.native
```

Comment: what about `Batteries`?

Comment: `Batteries` are included as dependency for `pa_comprehension`