# What's the purpose of _tags file with OCaml, and how to interpret the contents?

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild

From [Building OCaml code that uses list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28751359/building-ocaml-code-that-uses-list-comprehension) post, I can use `_tags` file to execute `ocamlbuild` with less build options.

```
$ cat _tags
<**/*> : package(camlp4),syntax(camlp4o),package(pa_comprehension)
```

From the [Batteries introduction](https://github.com/ocaml-batteries-team/batteries-included/wiki/Getting-started), I also need to have _tags file to use Batteries package.

```
<*>: package(batteries)
```

Why the first example uses `<**/*>` when the second example uses `<*>`? In general, what's the purpose of _tags file in ocamlbuild? Do you have some good tutorials on it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `_tags` file in addition to `myocamlbuild.ml` forms the root of the `ocamlbuild` compilation system.

`ocamlbuild` is a very generic tool, that can compile anything. It is driven by a solver, that according to the target, set by a user, finds a solution that can satisfy the target. The solution is a chain of rules that are applied to files. Files can be tagged by tags. Tags can alter rules. For example, it can add flags, like enabling profiling or linking to a library.

A `_tags` file provides a mechanism to assign tags to files and it has a simple grammar:

```
 pattern ":" tag "," {tag}.
```

What is to the left of `:` is actually a pattern or regular expression. Each file that matches the expression will be assigned with all tags that occur to the right of `:`.

`<**/*>` means for all files in this folder, and all subfolders, there is a shortcut for this: `true`. `<*>` means for all files on this folder (without descending into subfolders). Other examples are `<*.ml>`, `<*.cmx>` or `<**/*.cma>` (btw `or` can also be used to build a pattern).

OCamlbuild is documented in [OCaml Manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.02/ocamlbuild.html), also there is a [dump](http://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/ocamlbuild/) of old wiki, with lots of information.

But the fun part is that usually you do not need to know this in order to use OCaml. There is an [`OASIS`](https://ocaml.org/learn/tutorials/setting_up_with_oasis.html) tool that will automate all tasks, and create `_tags` file for you from a simple and high-level definition.