# How to access a member in a list on Ocaml

Tags: list, ocaml, camlp4

I have a source code below. I don't understand its syntax. 
`[g | t <- ts; g <- symbols t]` is very strange. Please help me to explain it or recommend any books or documents which correlates to it. Thank you very much

```
type term = V of string | F of string * term list

let rec symbols = function
  | V x -> [x]
  | F (f, ts) -> f :: [ g | t <- ts; g <- symbols t ]

let rec functions = function
  | V _ -> []
  | F (f, ts) -> f :: [ g | t <- ts; g <- functions t ]
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension

Answer (score 1):

This is a non standard syntax for [list comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension). I don't know any book that documents it. The idea is that it should resemble [set builder notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation). In short, this expression will be evaluated to list:

```
 [ x | p <- expr; p * 2 - 1 ]
```

where `expr`  should evaluate to lists, `p`  would be assigned to the corresponding elements of the list, so that the `p * 2 - 1` would be applied to each element of the original list.

In a normal OCaml syntax this can be expressed as

```
List.map (fun p -> p * 2 + 1) xs
```

As a final note, I wouldn't [suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27652428/list-comprehension-in-ocaml/27652530#27652530) you to use this list comprehension notation. It doesn't have tooling support, first off all, and is not common in modern OCaml anyway.

P.S. And example expression

```
f :: [ g | t <- ts; g <- symbols t ]
```

in vanilla OCaml is

```
f :: List.(map symbols ts |> concat)
```

Comment: It's suspicious. I think that this comprehention is more equal to `cartesian_product xs ys |> List.map (fun (x,y) -> x+y)`

Comment: yep, looks like that you're true, let me fix the post. Thanks

Comment: I think there is an issue again.  Function `symbols` returns a list but you seems to expect a signle value. Maybe you need to add `concat` somewhere....